init.lua - Remove default mapping recursively
I want to use the i_CTRL-G mapping to abort the current cmp selection, but i_CTRL-G is already used by neovim.
I tried to delete the mapping with this:
vim.keymap.del('i', '<C-g>')

But it just said: E31: No such mapping

Any ideas how to do this? :)

Could you tell us what is the result of the following Vim command: :verbose imap <C-g>?

omg you are a vim god. Seems like my vim-surround plugin sets the keymap. Here the output:
i  <C-G>S        <Plug>ISurround         Last set from ~/.config/nvim/pack/plugins/start/vim-surround/plugin/surround.vim line 626

Thanks. The mapping you have is not on <C-g> but on <C-g>S. You have to delete that mapping explicitly.

I think you rather want to disable the mapping, instead of deleting it: let g:surround_no_insert_mappings=1, see https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround/blob/3d188ed2113431cf8dac77be61b842acb64433d9/plugin/surround.vim#L621C15-L621C44

@ChristianBrabandt perfect addition. Write it as an answer so I can upvote it :)

There are no call that delete all the mapping that starts with a list of input.
You have to delete all the mapping individually.
In your example you have to do:
vim.keymap.del('i', '<C-g>S')

Or:
vim.api.nvim_del_keymap('i', '<C-g>S')


Once again thank you really much for your help :))))

Thanks for the feedback :-) The solution to your particular problem is probably to follow the advise of @ChristianBrabandt :-)

Yeah I used @ChristianBrabandt's solution, but without you I would have never found the cause of the issue. I didn't know you can find all the mappings with the :verbose <mode> <keys> command :))

Also question to you: Should I rename / delete my question, since it is not what I though it would be? It feels kinda wrong^^

That would be nice. It increase the chance from other to find your question and the corresponding answers.

Any suggestions? I have literally no idea what I should it rename it to^^

You can configure the vim-surround plugin to not create this insert mode mapping, by setting the following variable in your initialization script (assuming Vim here):
let g:surround_no_insert_mappings=1

Then you don't need to delete the mapping later on.
Taken from the plugin source
